# selenium: driver.close() from next function

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

Hello I use selenium to open a window in function parse
and I want to close it in function spider_detail
How can I do it??  Please guide me. Thank you

```
class ProductSpider(Spider):
    name = "debug1"
    start_urls = ['http://www.test.tw/in/5/'] 
    def parse(self, response):
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()  #open a window
        driver.get(response.url)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.media-body")))
   def spider_detail(self, spider):
        driver.close()        #close the window
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using scrapy, i normally do this

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher

class ProductSpider(Spider):
    name = "debug1"
    start_urls = ['http://www.test.tw/in/5/']

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        dispatcher.connect(self.close, signals.spider_closed)

    def close(self, spider):
        self.driver.quit()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.media-body")))

    def spider_detail(self, spider):
        self.driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally we close the driver using, driver.quit()

```
def spider_detail(self, spider):
        driver.quit()
```

Try this.

Comment: I try but it's no use fuction 2 can't get the variable from function 1